# use of "struct Foo" in field decl doesn't forward declare nested class

Tags: c++, scope, nested, forward-declaration

I am apparently misunderstanding how the C-ish feature of simultaneously "declaring" and referring to a type using `struct X` works in C++.  (Plus I don't even know what this feature is called, properly.)  I have three examples below to show what I'm doing but the main question is: Why is the nested type, forward declared in this way, at global scope instead of in class scope?

[This](http://ideone.com/EkgyRs) works to forward declare a nested struct:

```
#include <memory>
class Foo1
{
    Foo1();
    ~Foo1();
    struct Impl;
    std::auto_ptr<Impl> m_pimpl;
};

struct Foo1::Impl
{
    Impl(){}
    ~Impl(){}
};

Foo1::Foo1(){}
Foo1::~Foo1(){}

int main() {}
```

So now I want to save a few characters by using a half-remembered C feature, [so see](http://ideone.com/UdcAFB) where I've dropped the line `struct Impl;` and for the field declared its type  as `auto_ptr<struct Impl>` instead of `auto_ptr<Impl>`:

```
#include <memory>
class Foo2a
{
    Foo2a();
    ~Foo2a();
    std::auto_ptr<struct Impl> m_pimpl;
};

struct Foo2a::Impl
{
    Impl(){}
    ~Impl(){}
};

Foo2a::Foo2a(){}
Foo2a::~Foo2a(){}

int main() {}
```

Here the compiler complains that `no struct named 'Impl' in 'Foo2a'`.  Sure enough, it is at global scope, as [this](http://ideone.com/iVQL6W) compiles:

```
#include <memory>
class Foo2b
{
    Foo2b();
    ~Foo2b();
    std::auto_ptr<struct Impl> m_pimpl;
};

struct Impl
{
    Impl(){}
    ~Impl(){}
};

Foo2b::Foo2b(){}
Foo2b::~Foo2b(){}

int main() {}
```

What's up with that?  a) Why does it work at all to "declare" the type `Impl` this way, and b) given that it works, why is `Impl` at global scope not class scope?

And, BTW, declaring the field as `auto_ptr<struct Foo2c::Impl>` [doesn't work either](http://ideone.com/2r0X6p).

Comment: FYI: auto_ptr is deprecated and likely to be removed from the language soon. Consider using "std::unique_ptr" or "std::shared_ptr" instead.

Comment: @kfsone - thanks, it's just an example, substitute `std::shared_ptr` or `std::optional` if you wish.

Comment: The short answer is "because that's how C++ works".

Comment: @davidbak for this idiom substitute `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a name first declared as *elaborated-type-specifier* depends on the way in which it is used.

If you do `struct Impl;` the struct is declared as a member of whatever scope that declaration occurs in, as in your first example. But in any other context, it's declared in the nearest enclosing block or namespace (but not class), as in the second and third examples.

The solution is just to forward-declare it as `struct Impl;` in the class prior to any other uses. You can just refer to it as `Impl` after that.

See [basic.scope.cdecl]/7 for the detailed rules.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I know it is an _elaborated-type-specifier_ I found a good description of [what that is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier) (though it doesn't actually have the scope rule you described).