# How to forward-declare unnested class in a class body without befriending or declaring pointer

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I know two ways of declaring unnested class inside a class body.

First is:

```
class A
{
    friend class B; // B is forward-declared + friend
};
```

And the second is:

```
class A
{
    class B* ptr; // B is forward-declared + pointer
};
```

It's possible to forward-declare a class outside the class body, but for certain reason let's forget about this option;

So, I would like to make possible to declare such member:

```
class A
{
    /* somehow declare B in the body*/
    B* getInstanceB();
};
```

It's worth to mention, that:
With declaring a pointer:

```
class A
{
    class B* pointer;
    B* getInstanceB(); //fine
};
```

With friend declaration:

```
class A
{
    friend class B;
    B* getInstanceB(); //GCC 5.3.0 issues error, MSVC compiles
};
```

I deeply regret that there is no such forward-declaring syntax like:

`class ::[optional-namespace::]ClassName`;

which would distinguish nested class forward-declaration from unnested class forward-declaration. Is it possible to do that in current standard in some other way?

Comment: What's wrong with forward declaring `B` outside of `A`?

Comment: @erenon There is nothing wrong. But if there is another possibility, I would love to know it :)

Comment: Let me get this. You are trying to find out whether there is a different solution to a problem when there is an existing solution and it works just fine.

Comment: @R Sahu Don't be like that. I could use only pointers and never references, or I could use only macros instead of templates. Both works, and both can fail to certain degree.

Comment: @BlackMoses, that's fair. Just wanted to make sure I understood what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you want to forward-declare `B` inside `A` but have `B` be declared in namespace scope instead of in the scope of `A`?

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To forward-declare a class named `B` inside the class definition of `A` without having that class be nested within `A`, you can do something like the following:

```
class A {
    typedef class B B;
    // do something with B
};
```

An explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37713253/481267).

A demonstration that this actually does work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27913ce45a572d36

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to a forward declaration? (Test putting `B* ptr;` right after class A)

Comment: @DieterLücking The OP wants the forward declaration to be inside the class definition of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is have an instance of a class within another class but have the definition after the "container class"?

```
//forward declaration of B
class B;

class A
{
  public:
    B* getInstanceB();

  private:
     B b_;

};

B* A::getInstanceB()
{
   return &b_;
}

//implementation of B
class B{};
```

like this?

HTH

Comment: No, that's what I wanted to avoid in this example. It's about forward-declare B class inside class A body, not outside.

Comment: well you could just make a namespace statement inside your class A

see: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Answer (score 0):

> I deeply regret that there is no such forward-declaring syntax like:
>
> ```
> class ::[optional-namespace::]ClassName;
> ```
>
> which would distinguish nested class forward-declaration from unnested class forward-declaration. Is it possible to do that in current standard in some other way?

No, I don't think there is.